# Which tab was clicked on tabcontrol MouseClick event

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol, mouseclick-event

I am learning how to develop Windows Forms applications with Visual Basic Express 2008, and my testing/learning application has a TabControl with a few test pages (3, for example, the number isn't relevant here).

Now, I am handing the MouseClick event on the Tabcontrol, and I can't seem to be able to figure out how to get which tab was clicked on. 
I believe that the MouseClick event isn't fired if I click on another place of the tab strip, therefore a tab must have been clicked on. The problem is, which was the tab?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<strike>Don't use the `MouseClick` event, because there is another event better suited for this purpose:</strike>
 *(Note: edited after the OP has posted a comment.)*

`TabControl` has a **property `SelectedIndex`**. This is the zero-based number of the currently selected tab. (There is also another property called `SelectedTab`, referring directly to the selected tab page object.)

You can hook an event handler to the **event `SelectedIndexChanged`** in order to be notified whenever the user selects another tab:

```
Private Sub MyTabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
            Handles MyTabControl.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim indexOfSelectedTab As Integer = MyTabControl.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedTab As System.Windows.Forms.TabPage = MyTabControl.SelectedTab

    ...

End Sub
```

(Take note that you *might* want to additionally guard your code against cases where `SelectedIndex` has an invalid value, e.g. `-1`.)

**Edit (added after comment of OP)**:

If `SelectedIndexChanged` does not work for you because you need to catch the user's action for all mouse buttons, you could use the **`GetTabRect` method** of `TabControl` like this:

```
Private Sub MyTabControl_MouseClick(sender As Object, _
                                    e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
            Handles MyTabControl.MouseClick

    ...

    For tabIndex As Integer = 0 To MyTabControl.TabCount - 1
        If MyTabControl.GetTabRect(tabIndex).Contains(e.Location) Then
           ...  ' clicked on tab with index tabIndex '
        End If
    Next

    ...

End Sub
```

Comment: This will work for a regular mouseclick, but what about a middle click? Middle clicking won't change the selected tab. Thanks for this though, this case is now working but I need to check which tab was middle-clicked on, also. should I open a new question?

Comment: It is a different question, but see my expanded answer for now.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to accomplish the middle click?

Comment: @Pedro, read the second part of my answer. All you would need to do is change the `If` condition to: `MyTabControl.GetTabRect(…).Contains(…)` **`AndAlso e.Button = MouseButtons.Middle`**. I just tried it, works like a charm. You will know which tab was clicked by the `tabIndex` variable. You could e.g. use it as an index into the `MyTabControl.TabPages` collection.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I use to handle this would be to use the ENTER and LEAVE events for each tabpage's event. For Example I have it so that when I leave the first page it changes the visible property to my datagridview to False and when I enter it turns it back to True and loads the data for my table.

```
Private Sub TabPage1_Enter(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Enter
    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    Load_Table()
End Sub

Private Sub TabPage1_Leave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Leave
    DataGridView1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

If you wanted to change the text on the control or something like that I suppose the index method would be the choice way to go, but just to know which tab was clicked that is what these two events are for.